# How can I populate combobox items from a database and not copy the same code everywhere (how do I change my code to use OOP)?

Tags: c#, sql, oop, design-patterns, architecture

```
SqlDataReader myreader = null;
    SqlConnection sqlConn = null;

     cmbCat.Items.Clear();
    sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tin;Initial Catalog=sample;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    sqlConn.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT members FROM  dbo.tbl_Category", sqlConn);

    myreader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
    if (myreader != null)
    {
        while (myreader.Read())
        {

            cmbCat.Items.Add(myreader["members"]);

        }
    }

    {
        if (myreader != null)
            myreader.Close();
        if (sqlConn != null)
        {
            if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have this following code in retrieving data from the database into the combobox. I always place this code everytime I need to populate a data into the combobox from the database. What I want to do is reconstruct this code and place it in a class and what will I do is just call the function that will be responsible in populating data into the combobox. But I am confused on how to do it. Please help me. Thank you in advanced. Have a good day..

Answer (score 4):

You have several concerns in the code you posted.  I'll try to provide a simplified set of code, but if you separate the various needs (concerns) of this little bit of code, you will find many distinct classes, but I digress.

First, you do **NOT** want to be spreading your connection string everywhere in your application with COPY-PASTE.  You should create a dedicated class to handle this.

```
public class DatabaseGateway
{
  public IList<T> RetrieveSqlAs<T>(string queryString, ITransformer<SqlDataReader, T> rowTransformer)
  {
    var result = new List<T>();
    using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  // you can use a CONSTANT, or call to a .config file here
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConn))
    {
      var myreader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
      while (myreader.Read())
      {
         result.Add(rowTransformer.Transform(myreader));
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}

public class MemberRowTransformer : ITransformer<SqlDataReader, string>
{
  public string Transform(SqlDataReader from)
  {
    from["members"];  // handle null and anything else here
  }
}

public interface ITransformer<TFrom, TTo>
{
  TTo Transform(TFrom)
}
```

Then you use it like:

```
var gateway = new DatabaseGateway();
var transformer = new MemberRowTransformer();

cmb.Items.Clear();
foreach (string i in gateway.RetrieveSqlAs("SELECT members FROM  dbo.tbl_Category", transformer))
{
  cmb.Items.Add(i);
}
```

If you're with me so far, just go one more step towards a `Repository Pattern`.  Add this class:

```
public class MembershipRepository
{
   public List<string> GetMembers()
   {
     var gateway = new DatabaseGateway();
     var transformer = new MemberRowTransformer();
     var result = new List<string>();

     foreach (string i in gateway.RetrieveSqlAs("SELECT members FROM  dbo.tbl_Category", transformer))
     {
       result.Add(i);
     }

     return result;
   }
}
```

Then your calling code becomes:

```
var repository = new MembershipRepository();
cmb.Items.Clear();
foreach(string i in repository.GetMembers())
{
   cmb.Items.Add(i);
}
```

If you look into the topics of: Generics, Repository Pattern and Data Transfer Objects (DTOs), you will find many good ideas on how to create classes that you can re-use instead of duplicating code.

**Note:** I have not gone through the entire exercise of splitting things out into Interfaces so that you can do easy Unit Testing and Dependency Injection, that is a larger topic, but a good thing to check out as well!

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want to keep presentation logic separate from business/data access logic.  So your data access code should return the data in a generic form, such as a `DataTable` or some sort of custom Collection.  Then your calling code on the form would be responsible for populating it into the combobox:

```
public List<string> GetCategories()
{
    List<string> cats = new List<string>();
    SqlDataReader myreader = null;
    ...
    while (myreader.Read())
        cats.Add((string)myreader["members"]);
    ...
    return cats;
}
```

Then in your form, you'd do something like this:

```
protected void DoDataBinding()
{
    MyDataAccessClass dataAccess = new MyDataAccessClass();
    List<string> cats = dataAccess.GetCategories();
    cmb.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string cat in cats)
        cmb.Items.Add(cat);
}
```